# How to implement mobile simulation in DotNetbrowser

Tags: c#, click, touch

How to implement mobile simulation in DotNetbrowser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to emulate a mobile device in Edge? Is that what you're asking?

Here is a link showing how to emulate different devices and views in that browser: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/emulation